# Widevine android framework DrmInfoRequest send as HTTP POST

Tags: android, drm, widevine

When I use the widevine android framework and I try to call DrmInfoRequest I need it to send it as a HTTP POST and it keeps sending it as a HTTP GET requet, is there anyway to change this behavior (any parameter to set in the call, configuration)? 
I have to have it as a POST for my server.

Answer (score 0):

After a lock of fidgeting we ended up putting some data in the payload and this made it send it as POST.